# Trigonometric equation; finding all solutions

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having a hard time with trigonometric equations. I need to find all solutions to the following equation: $$4\sin^2 θ=3$$ Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Your equation reduces to 2 cases:

$$\sin\theta= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ and $$\sin\theta= -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $$

Comment: I edited the denominator to be $2$ and not $4$

Comment: Oh my.. such a pathetic silly mistake.. thank you sir! Was in a hurry... @marwalix

Comment: Thanks. My ans: θ= 66, 120, 240 & 300 degrees. Is that correct?

Comment: In radians, the solution will be $\pi n - \frac{4\pi}{3}$ and $\pi n - \frac{2\pi}{3}$ .. for $n \in Z$

Comment: So 60, 120, 240, 300 are solutions. Besides 66, your other solutions are right. @Jeansilvy

Comment: Oops, thanks. Helped a lot.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to MathStackexhange! If you find an answer or a question good, please do upvote it.

Comment: @Kugelblitz I will. For giving hints rather than the complete solution .+1

Comment: @Klosew That's very kind of you! Since OP was new, I was just giving a tip, because people (Shamefully, even me to an extent) like being upvoted on this site... (Note: I want upvotes, I admit it. The thing is, the reason for that is not so selfish; I wish to give bounties to more questions for their wonderful answers.. I've offered 6 already, with two on others' questions..)

Comment: @Kugelblitz I am not against your tip . New users usually just accept the answers as they cant vote at that time . On crossing 15 rep , they usually dont upvote their previous answerers rather just the future ones .

Comment: Is it so? I thought upvotes are possible from Rep 1.. well, you learn something new everyday.. thanks once again! @Klosew

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the equation as 
$$4\sin^2\theta-2=1\iff -2\cos 2\theta=1\iff\cos 2\theta=-\frac12$$
so the solutions are:
$$2\theta\equiv \pm \frac{2\pi}3\mod 2\pi\iff \theta\equiv \pm\frac\pi3\mod \pi.$$